# How to use re.compile with class in BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a page with different css classes as follows:

```
class="mod result idx0 people"
class="mod result idx1 people"
class="mod result idx2 people"
class="mod result idx3 people"
class="mod result idx4 people"
```

I am using `bs4` and `html5lib` with `Python2.7`

Now when I do this for first element above I get the results positively.

```
soup.find(class_="mod result idx0 people")
```

However, I want to do this for all the classes.

So I am trying all of them but am still getting an empty list `[]`. What am I doing wrong?

```
soup.find_all(class_="mod result")
soup.find_all(class_=re.compile("mod result"))
soup.find_all("li",{"class":re.compile("mod result")})
soup.find_all("li",attrs={"class":re.compile("mod result")})
soup.find_all({"class":re.compile("mod result")})
```

None of them are working :-(

Comment: So someone stupid edited my question - then someone smart changed it again back to what I posted... and in between I get marked down for posting incorrect question --- wow :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to ([Beautiful Soup documentation - Search by CSS class](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#searching-by-css-class)), if you want to search for tags that match two or more CSS classes, you should use a CSS selector.

```
soup.select('.mod.result')
```

Comment: Yepiie :-) Thanks again falsetru :-) Never knew classes have to dealt with css. I always preferred find method. But I guess I have to learn this now :-) But it does work. Thank you so much